# Running program in SCTP

Tags: tcp, network-programming, ip, host, sctp

I need to create a program that sends messages, using SCTP, from host A to host B.

The problem is... I don't know how do run this program. How can I, using language C, send messages from one host to another.

Any vague answer is welcomed.

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. The site is not working this way. You need first to do your own research and try a solution. Then if the solution doesn't work as expected, you may ask for help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

SCTP is a transport layer protocol, and the operating system has built-in transport layer protocols, including SCTP and you get to choose what protocol it uses. 
But I think here is what you're looking for: http://simplestcodings.blogspot.com/2010/08/sctp-server-client-implementation-in-c.html
a demo implementation of SCTP above tcp/ip.